# Suzuki GZ125 2003 - what size fuel line?

Tags: suzuki, fuel-line

I need to buy a new tank for my gz125 k3 and I need to get some new fuel cable for the tank to the carb. Does anyone know what size the line needs to be to fit snug?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to be sure is to look at the hose you are replacing but it should be a 4mm inner diameter 6mm outer diameter. Suzuki P/N: 0935240703600